# Two ways to evaluate a probability — different results.

Tags: probability, fake-proofs

I was recently trying to solve a rather simple probability question. Notwithstanding, when I compared both approaches, I noticed that the outcomes were different, and was wandering if someone could explain me where it went wrong.

> *The problem.* A cooking course is given, attended by four experienced participants and eight new ones. It is known that new participants attend the course with a $90\%$ probability, while those who have attended in previous years do so with a $75\%$ probability.

> Determine the probability, that at least $11$ participants will attend today's lesson.

**Approach 1.** Notice that at least $11$ participants will attend the course today iff

- $8$ new and $4$ experienced participants do so.
- $8$ new and $3$ experienced participants do so.
- $7$ new and $4$ experienced participants do so.

Define the variables $A="\text{number of new participants attending todays course}"$ and $B$ similarly for experienced participants. Then we are asked to evaluate $$P(A=8)\cdot P(B=4)+P(A=8)\cdot P(B=3)+P(A=7)\cdot P(B=4)=\ldots\approx 43,8\%$$

**Approach 2.** We consider the probability that a random selected participant will attend the course today. This is $$p=\frac{0.9\cdot8+0.75\cdot 4}{12}=0.85$$ Thus, if $X$ denotes the amount of participants attending today's lesson we should have $$P(X\geqslant 11)=P(X=11)+P(X=12)=\binom{12}{11}\cdot (0.85)^{11}\cdot 0.15+0.85^{12}\approx 44.3\%$$

I am confident that the first approach is correct, and, hence, the answer should be $43,8\%$. But, *what's wrong with the second approach*? I am looking for both rigorous and intuitive ways of showing that the latter approach does not work. Thanks :)

Comment: To illustrate the problem with approach $2$, suppose that the $8$ new ones attend a lecture with probability $1$, but that the old ones never attend (so probability $0$).  In that case it is, of course, impossible that $11$ attend.  But method $2$ gives a positive answer.

Comment: The problem is independence.  Knowing that the first student attends (or fails to) is evidence as to which sort they are and changes the probability of that changes the computation for the others.  In my extreme example, seeing that student $1$ shows up proves he/she is new, for instance. Try it with two students where the computation is easier.

Comment: To put rigorously, the "average probability" in the second case can be defined as the expected value of "number of people per round of selection". As pointed out by lulu, $E(X\cap Y)=E(X)\cdot E(Y)$ only happens when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @cr001 and is there a formula for $E(X\cup Y)$ when $X,Y$ are dependent?

Comment: Btw, Thanks @lulu and @cr001! Your explanations made the mistake clear!